# Debian Kernel headers 3.15

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I'm using Debian Sid with kernel 3.15 RC7. I installed it from the experimental repo with no problem. I also need to install  the kernel headers, because I need to compile a module. The headers are included in the following package:
https://packages.debian.org/experimental/kernel/linux-headers-3.15-rc7-686-pae
The problem is that: this package depends on linux-kbuild-3.15 package, and this is not available yet, therefore I cannot install the headers neither.
Is there any other way I could install linux-headers 3.15? Or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved my issue by building linux-kbuild myself. This page also suggests it:

"Often, when a new kernel comes around, linux-kbuild-3.xx isn't yet available in the archive, so you either have to build it yourself, or wait." - https://wiki.debian.org/HowToRebuildAnOfficialDebianKernelPackage

There is also a step-by-step tutorial on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the kernel, or is it a .DEB package? If you compiled it from source then you're in luck. After I mark my options using "make menuconfig" I simply run "make deb-pkg". The result will give you the "linux-firmware-image", "linux-image", "linux-libc-dev", and "linux-headers" packages in DEB format. After a "dpkg -i *deb" and reboot, you now have your new kernel with headers and the rest.

Comment: I did not compile it, I installed it from the experimental repository.